# Moving image in python tkinter

Tags: python, image, animation, tkinter, png

I am writing a simple program in which I want the (ball image png) to bounce off the walls. So far, I have writen this code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 500

canvas = tk.Canvas(root,bg="white",width=WIDTH,height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()

img = tk.PhotoImage(file="images/ball1.png")
ball = canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor="nw",image=img)

yspeed = 2
xspeed = 2

def move_ball():
    global xspeed,yspeed,ball
    canvas.move(ball,xspeed,yspeed)
    canvas.after(10,move_ball)

move_ball()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any code where you've tried to do any sort of edge detection.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current position with the `coords` method, then code in a check for each of the 4 walls. Here's the first one:

```
def move_ball():
    global xspeed,yspeed,ball
    xpos, ypos = canvas.coords(ball)
    if xpos + width_of_ball > WIDTH:
        # ball hit the right edge, reverse x direction
        xspeed *= -1
    canvas.move(ball,xspeed,yspeed)
    canvas.after(10,move_ball)
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is the same thing as @Novel answer (even though I wrote it before I saw theirs). The only difference is in the fact that the logic of `update` doesn't expect you to make any edits for it to work, it considers both horizontal and vertical directions, and resizing the main window is compensated for.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Infinite Bounce Simulator')
root.geometry('400x300+300+300')

xspeed = 4
yspeed = 3

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, highlightthickness=0, bg='#111')
canvas.pack(expand=True, fill='both')    

ball   = canvas.create_oval((0, 0, 20, 20), fill='red')

def update():
    global xspeed, yspeed, ball
    
    canvas.move(ball, xspeed, yspeed)
    
    #Left, Top, Right, Bottom coordinates
    l, t, r, b = canvas.coords(ball)
    
    #flip speeds when edges are reached
    if r > canvas.winfo_width()  or l < 0:
        xspeed = -xspeed 
    if b > canvas.winfo_height() or t < 0:
        yspeed = -yspeed           
        
    #do it all again in 10 milliseconds
    root.after(10, update)
    
    
root.after_idle(update)    
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you added at least a tiny explanation, so the reader doesn't have to compare your code to the original line-by-line and character-by-character.

Comment: @BryanOakley I agree but, it's all so obvious that I felt like explaining it would be silly. I'll add something.

Comment: Why don't you use `x1` instead of `x+w` in `if x+w > canvas.winfo_width() ...`?  Same for `y1` and `y+h`.

Comment: @acw1668 ~ Apparently, that is too simple and obvious :D. Good eye.